# JavaScript object with multiple values

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to build a set of questions and answers for a questionnaire. Each instance has an id, a css class, a question, and *at least one* answer. Is it possible to have multiple values when there is more than one answer?

```
var qa = [
{id: "0", css: "multiple", question: "Do you own a home?", answers: "Yes", "No"},
{id: "1", css: "input", question: "Who will live in your home?", answer: "<textarea rows='5' class='textarea'></textarea>"}
];
```

Comment: Yes, by using arrays! `... answers: ["Yes", "No"]`

Comment: Is the code in your question working or is it an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @EternalHour The code has a syntax error. So it's not working.

Comment: Note that your question has nothing to do with jQuery. You have defined a _JavaScript_ array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by turning the **answers** in to an array:

```
var qa = [{
            id: "0",
            css: "multiple",
            question: "Do you own a home?",
            answers: ["Yes", "No"]
}];
```

And than access it like this:

```
qa[0].answers[0] // for "Yes"
qa[0].answers[1] // for "No"
```

**or**

```
qa[0]['answers'][0]// for "Yes"
qa[0]['answers'][1] // for "No"
```

Or instead of an array you also can use an object:

```
var qa = [{
           id: "0",
           css: "multiple",
           question: "Do you own a home?",
           answers: [yes: "Yes", no: "No"]
}];
```

And than access it like this:

```
qa[0].answers.yes // for "Yes"
qa[0].answers.no // for "No"
```

**or**

```
qa[0]['answers']['yes']// for "Yes"
qa[0]['answers']['no'] // for "No"
```